# Angled lines on background CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, background

I want to create this kind of design:

[image: Design preview]

How can I create this angled lines levels?

Right now I am designing with css/sass and Bootstrap.
My starting point is this:
http://demo.themefisher.com/demos/?theme=vex

As you can see, it his built to seperate the areas by levels, I would just this levels to become a parallelogram instead of an ordinary rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #999;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    margin-left: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

---

is this satisfy you?
[image]

Comment: No... Not really what I was asking for. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Randomizer check again

Comment: this must what you looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can replace you background color with a multiple background using gradient:

```css
.box {
  padding:50px 0;
  background:
   /* Triangle at the top width:100% height:50px*/
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,orange 50%) top/100% 50px,
   /* Rectangle in the center filling the remaining space*/
   linear-gradient(orange,orange) center/100% calc(100% - 100px),
   /* Triangle at the bottom width:100% height:50px*/
   linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,orange 50%) bottom/100% 50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h2>Designed By Professional , The Benefit For Creative Gigs</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia vel labore, deleniti minima nisi, velit atque quaerat impedit ea maxime sunt accusamus at obcaecati dolor iure iusto omnis quis eum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis commodi odit, illo, qui aliquam dol
</div>
```